# Need help to resolve equation with delta

Tags: statistics, inequality, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared

Hello I need to solve this equation, I have the result but I do not understand how we solve it:

> [image]

$\Delta n$ is the difference between the expected and observed number in a $\chi^2$, we try to find out how many individuals would have been needed to reject $H_0$.

I do not understand the part where $\Delta n \ge 14.919$ becomes $n \ge 246.669$ or $n \le 216.831$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average of $246.669$ and $216.831$ is $231.75,$ which is $14.919$ away from either bound.